# conditional statement based formatting of XML responses from php curl

Tags: php, xml, curl, infobip, infobip-api

I am having difficulty formatting the XML response from a php curl XML API for INFOBIP. My code below loops SMS to mobile numbers. But I want to format the XML responses to show the messages successfully sent and those that were not successful using a conditional if else statement.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    // XML-formatted data
    $xmlString='
            <SMS>
               <authentication>
                  <username>'.$user.'</username>
                  <password>'.$pass.'</password>
               </authentication>
               <message>
                  <sender>'.$sender.'</sender>
                  <text>'.$message.'</text>
                  <recipients>


                     <gsm>'.$mobileno.'</gsm>
        //<gsm>'.$mobileno1.'</gsm>


                  </recipients>
               </message>
            </SMS>';

    $fields = "XML=" . urlencode($xmlString);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); 


// Successfully sent messages usually outputs <status>0<status>  while unsuccessful outputs 1,2,3

if($xml->status == '0') {
echo "message successfully delivered to ".$mobileno. "<br>" ;
}else{
echo "error sending message to ".$mobileno."<br>" ;

  }

   }
```

The problem I have is being able to set or parse the XML responses to get the `<status>` if successfully sent or not based on the XML status response. Currently this how the XML responses outputs the results without formatting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<results> 
<result><status>1</status><messageid></messageid><destination>23421</destination></result> </results>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <results> <result><status>-13</status><messageid></messageid><destination>23412</destination></result> </results>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <results> <result><status>0</status><messageid></messageid><destination>23444</destination></result> 
</results>
```

Comment: Its because your xml is not valid, check it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Comment: having multiple `prologs` in xml is not valid - use `str_replace` to remove them before attempting to parse the xml

Comment: @RamRaider Pls can you show me a sample code using str_replace to remove the prolog before parsing the XML. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str_soap_xml='
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <results> 
        <result>
            <status>1</status>
            <messageid></messageid>
            <destination>23421</destination>
        </result>
    </results>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
        <result>
            <status>-13</status>
            <messageid></messageid>
            <destination>23412</destination>
        </result>
    </results>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
        <result>
            <status>0</status>
            <messageid></messageid>
            <destination>23444</destination>
        </result> 
    </results>';

/*
    manipulate the dodgy, invalid xml by firstly stripping out the XML Prologs
    then give a new ROOT node ( as valid xml can only have one root node )
    and then, to make sure, append a new XML Prolog
*/
$str_soap_xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>'.trim( str_replace( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '', $str_soap_xml ) ).'</root>';


$total=0;
define('BR','<br />');

/* create the domdocument object & load the string */
$dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$dom->loadXML( $str_soap_xml );
/* find all result nodes */
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('result');

/* iterate through each result and find it's children */
foreach( $col as $node ){
    foreach( $node->childNodes as $child ){
        echo $child->tagName.' '.$child->nodeValue.BR;
        if( $child->tagName=='status' && $child->nodeValue==0 ) echo 'Bad foo!';
        elseif( $child->tagName=='status' ) $total++;
    }
}
$dom=$col=$node=$child=null;
echo 'total: '.$total.' add this to db';
```

Comment: I tried this out by substituting $str_soap_xml with $response. 
 Since my xml result was generated from 
$response = curl_exec($ch);

But i didn't output anything apart from the actual un formatted XML response.

Comment: I'm not surprised that you were getting the raw data printed to screen - you need to supply the return transfer option to the curl request. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

Comment: It appears to be outputting a better formatted response now. I got status -13BRmessageid BRdestination 234343BRstatus -13BRmessageid BRdestination 234332BR . So i replaced the BR with '<BR>' to break into lines.  How can i now write the conditional statement to check if status value is == '0'  in order to flag the message as successful and otherwise as unsuccessful.

Comment: the `BR` is simply a constant ( which I forgot to define in the answer ) for th html `br` tag

Comment: How do i manipulate this part
foreach( $col as $node ){
    foreach( $node->childNodes as $child ){
        echo $child->tagName.' '.$child->nodeValue.'<br>';
    }
}

So that it outputs successful if <status> is 0 and unsuccessful for otherwise.

Comment: see last change above

Comment: I have used your modification to achieve was trying to do. 
One last thing i would love to add as to get a sum total count of all successful messages in my loop. How can get this value so i  can store it in a mysql field

Comment: I tried using your exact code but got a total value of -12 instead of 1 the correct total count of successful messages sent. Do you have any idea what the issue could be ?

Comment: is it possible to write the response output to php variable ?

Comment: yes. which `response output` do you mean? If it is the entire output from the DOMDocument processing - add items to an array and use that as your php variable

Comment: Yes the entire out put.
now my formatted output looks like this 

`Error Sending to 2344
Error Sending to 2342
Successfully sent to 2348034057037
Total Successful count is 1`

Comment: Do you know what could be responsible for this error i am getting ? I added a timezone code date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");
I get this error ===> 
[20-Feb-2016 15:05:13 Africa/Lagos] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1 in